# Reaching between OVS bridges

Tags: network-programming, switching, openvswitch

want to ping different Open vSwitch bridges via a physical interface. My host has an eth1 and a wlan0 interface. I have created 3 OVS bridges and assigned IP addresses to them. wlan0 added to br0. Two virtual interface wlan0.1 and wlan0.2 is created by wlan0 and added them to br1 and br2. Another bridge breth is connected to eth1 interface and all other bridges are connected to breth by patch port. [see the figure bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnTcM.jpg)
Now, host can ping all 3 brides. There are similar host in the network connected via wlan0 interface. They are under mesh network. Any host can ping any node's any bridge. But a PC is connected to eth1 interface only can ping br0 and other host's br0. That means, bridges assigned virtual interface are unreachable from PC. Is there any way to reach other bridges?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you are able to see the picture, then the problem is I want to reach all bridges inside the host from client. If you match my figure with text side by side, then you will find it is pretty much straightforward description of the problem.